# discord.py how to get a list of members with a specific role?

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py, bots

I need to get a list of participants with a special role on the server, so that I can send them messages.Who knows how this could be done please help me, I tried to find an answer to this question, but nothing works

Comment: What have you tried so far? What are your approaches? Please make an honest attemp to solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

See the documentation for [`discord.Role.members`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=role#discord.Role.members).